# Quiet door latch

Tags: doors, doorknob

I have a bathroom door that is quite loud when operated. And when someone goes to the bathroom at night, it innevatibly wakes someone up (and baby room is just across from the bathroom!) there are 3 components of noise, and I was wondering if there is an alternative to fixing them:

- door bangs against the jamb (this is fixed with simple foam bumpers)
- latch mechanism makes a loud CLUNK when door is pushed closed (I was able to dampen it just a bit by putting foam inside strike plate, but it is still quite loud)
- lock button also makes a CLUNK when the knob is turned and it is released (this can be battled by replacing with a mechanism that needs to be manually opened [twist instead of push] but it is less convenient, and I would prefer something that automatically unlocks)

Any suggestions as to a knob that has a dampening of the latch and lock button? I have only found one youtube video of my ideal handle, but there is no information on how it works, where to buy it, or anything else: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GniHw2g_iII

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the bathroom door held closed, remove the latch mechanism totally, install a dummy knob and use a magnetic closure to hold the door in place.

You do not even need the magnet to touch the matched plate on the stronger ones. If you are using a bit of foam or a vinyl bumper on the door itself, adjust the magnet back from the plate until it is about 1/16 inch away. It will hold without a *click*.

If you need a lock for other times, use a surface mounted privacy bolt.

Comment: I was also thinking about that, but would like to keep it as a last resort :) Although this will address most problems, elegant solution with a knob is preferred.

Comment: Just realize that some of these magnets are really strong.  I did this with a garbage can drawer that wouldn't stay closed and you really have to use a good bit of force to open it and the handle keeps coming loose.  You may not need the strongest option available.

Answer (score 2):

A door/knob that is set properly will make very little noise during normal operation. The noise caused by the door hitting the jamb is almost certainly a function of misalignment (i.e. the door is striking the jamb stop at only one location). When properly hung the tight tolerances will trap air as the door closes and create a natural cushioning effect. Either rehang your door or better yet, upgrade to a solid core door (i'm assuming yours is a hollow core, most are these days). Solid doors will operate smoother and quieter (not to mention blocking out more sound from inside the bathroom) and transmit less sound from the action of the handle/lock. Which brings me to your second and third issues. Upgrading to a new handle is usually pretty painless, provided your mortises and backsets are all standard. The one in the video looks neat but I've never heard of that manufacturer and the video looked decidedly home grown so... caveat emptor. In general the nicer the latch, the nicer it will operate. You don't have to spend a fortune but don't go buy the $20 kwickset from Home Depot or you'll be disappointed, get one with some heft. I would caution against a lever style since you have small children as they are much easier to operate and in my opinion more difficult to child proof.

Comment: First issue is easy, my main concern is the other two. I went to couple hardware stores, tried ALL of the knobs on display, and none of them is nearly good enough. I'd like to see one that is silent. If you have one, may be youtube it's operation when the door is just pushed closed (without turning the knob)?